# NaN in a mathematical equation

Tags: javascript, math

So I got this mathematical equation and I need to write it in pure JS using the Math object obviously.

I looked up at the docs about the required methods to solve it, but I get the NaN in the console when I output the result.

I suppose it's my stupid brain that cannot solve this correctly

Here's the code:

```js
let
  z = 5
, x = 10
, y = 2
, b = Math.cos(Math.pow(2)) * z + Math.tan(2 * x) + Math.abs(y)
  ;
console.log(b);
```

[image]

Comment: `Math.pow(2)` is NaN, because it lacks a second argument.

Comment: [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) takes *two* arguments.

Comment: Is "*tg* 2 *x*" intended to be "tan 2 *x*"?

Comment: cos^2 z is not how you wrote it to solve it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prefer to use [Exponentiation (**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation)

```js
let
  z = 5
, x = 10
, y = 2
, b = Math.cos(z)**2 + Math.tan(2 * x) + Math.abs(y)
  ;
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Math.pow()` incorrectly. The method takes two arguments, the base and the power.

I believe your expression `b` should look like this:

```
b = Math.pow(Math.cos(z), 2) + Math.tan(2 * x) + Math.abs(y)
```